# Why crypto.pbkdf2Sync get executed before setTimeout() in Node JS?

Tags: node.js

I'm struggled to understand how crypto's result returned before nextTick, Immediate or timeout.
I know this is synchronous crypto so it block the event loop, but how exactly it block when others function got called first and time to finish is faster than cryto? 
The order of code line here is not important?

```
const fs = require('fs');
const crypto = require('crypto');
const start = Date.now();

setTimeout(() => console.log('Timer 1 finished'), 0);
setImmediate(() => console.log('Immediate 1 finished'));

fs.readFile('test-file.txt', () => {
  console.log('Reading file.... and finished');
  console.log('-----------------');

  setTimeout(() => console.log('Timer 2 finished'), 0);
  setTimeout(() => console.log('Timer 3 finished'), 2000);
  setImmediate(() => console.log('Immediate 2 finished'));
  process.nextTick(() => console.log('Process nextTick'));

  crypto.pbkdf2Sync('password', 'salt', 100000, 1024, 'sha512');
  console.log(Date.now() - start, 'Password encrypted');

  crypto.pbkdf2Sync('password', 'salt', 100000, 1024, 'sha512');
  console.log(Date.now() - start, 'Password encrypted');

  crypto.pbkdf2Sync('password', 'salt', 100000, 1024, 'sha512');
  console.log(Date.now() - start, 'Password encrypted');

  crypto.pbkdf2Sync('password', 'salt', 100000, 1024, 'sha512');
  console.log(Date.now() - start, 'Password encrypted');

});
```

Result

```
Timer 1 finished
Immediate 1 finished
Reading file.... and finished
-----------------
2003 'Password encrypted'
3980 'Password encrypted'
5961 'Password encrypted'
7961 'Password encrypted'
Process nextTick
Immediate 2 finished
Timer 2 finished
Timer 3 finished
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> Why crypto.pbkdf2Sync get executed before setTimeout() in Node JS?

In a nushell, because `crypto.pbkdf2Sync()` is synchronous and node.js must complete all synchronous code in the current event processing before it can process the completion of any other asycnhronous operations.

`setTimeout()`, `setImmediate()` and `process.nextTick()` all schedule their callback for a FUTURE tick of the event loop.  When it's their turn to run, they insert a callback into the event queue.  But, NOTHING in the event queue gets to run until the current piece of Javascript is done executing.  So, that means that ALL the synchronous code in your `fs.readFile()` callback runs to completion before anything else can be pulled from the event queue and run.

This sequencing is all because of the "event-driven" nature of node.js.  Asynchronous operations always complete on a future tick of the event loop, thus any synchronous code that is already in the process of running must complete before any asynchronous operation can get its completion callback called, even if the asynchronous operation is of the "very-soon" types such as `setTimeout(..., 0)`, `process.nextTick()` or `.setImmediate()`.

So, the sequence of events goes like this (ignoring the things before `fs.readFile()` as they aren't relevant since they both occur before the `fs.ReadFile()` callback completes.

1. Call `fs.readFile()`.  It starts the file operation and immediately returns.
2. Node.js goes back to event loop and waits for the next event.
3. `fs.feadFile()` completes and inserts a completion callback event in the event queue.
4. When the interpreter has finished anything else it was running, it grabs the next event from the event queue and calls the `fs.feadFile()` callback.
5. `setTimeout(..., 0)` is called.  That schedules a timer event for the next tick of the event loop.
6. `setTimeout(..., 2000)` is called.  That schedules a timer event for 2 seconds from now.
7. `setImmediate(...)` is called.  That schedules an event for a future tick of the event loop.
8. `crypto.pbkdf2Sync(...)` is called.  This is a synchronous operation so it runs immediately and then finishes.
9. `crypto.pbkdf2Sync(...)` is called.  This is a synchronous operation so it runs immediately and then finishes.
10. `crypto.pbkdf2Sync(...)` is called.  This is a synchronous operation so it runs immediately and then finishes.
11. `crypto.pbkdf2Sync(...)` is called.  This is a synchronous operation so it runs immediately and then finishes.
12. The callback for `fs.readFile()` finishes.  The JS interpreter then pulls the next event from the event queue.
13. Based on the circumstances and the relevant priority of various types of events, the next item pulled from the event queue is the `process.nextTick()` callback.
14. Then, the `setImmediate()` event.
15. Then, the `setTimeout(..., 0)`.
16. Then, after some delay, the `setTimeout(..., 2000)`.

Comment: Man, this is a perfect answer. Thank you so much, pal. Yes, this is what I want to hear. Even asynchronous operation is of the "very-soon" types such as setTimeout(..., 0), process.nextTick() or .setImmediate()

Comment: I watched "WTH is Event Loop" on Youtube and thought I understood correctly but no articles/tutorials out there mentioned the time to finish of async/sync code so I got a little confused.